# Move my internet to camper

Tags: internet

We are remodeling our house and moved in a camper in the driveway for the mean time. How do I run internet into the camper?
We know exactly where the pole where the main internet cable runs. We unhooked it from where it would run to the house and hooked up a new cable and ran it in to the camper and our modem still says offline
We have spectrum.

Comment: With it being Spectrum, is the new cable you ran Ethernet or coax? With cable internet providers, they connect to the ISP over coax.

Comment: Should we know what is "spectrum"? Also more details about what kind of cable is this will be helpful.

Comment: @RomeoNinov it is not unreasonable for someone to talk about "Spectrum" - They are a large ISP covering many parts of the USA - I've heard of them and I don't even live there.

Comment: @davidgo, it is wise to mention these details in the question.

Comment: I’m not trying to be rude, but how do you expect us to solve this problem for you? If the modem were hooked up the same as it was in the house, it would work. Double check your connections.